# Run and build project C++ in cmd

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I started learning C ++ on VScode but prefer to create projects in cmd. When I found out, I could not use the cl command on cmd even though I have installed buildtools 2019 already. Help me!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bidq1.png)

Comment: Download Visual Studio, then use msbuild to build your projects from the command line.

Comment: Search for the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" shortcut, it opens an instance of cmd with the appropriate environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open an "Developer Command Prompt" and run the command there.

[image]

Comment: Use the x64 one if you want to build a 64 bit application. I mention this because in 2019 it is rare that I build 32 bit builds.

Comment: Thank you very much